# How to manually swap/combine faces without auto blend layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make some editing involving anime characters.
The problem is that whenever I try to use auto blend layers, my entire composition gets destroyed.
Color getting all over the place (as you see in the following images).

Before auto blend:

[image]

After auto blend:

[image]

I tried searching online for face swaps or merge tutorial but every single one of them is using auto blend layers function, which I would like to avoid since every time I use it with anime the entire picture gets ruined.

How can I achieve this without using auto blend? And why is auto blend acting like that in the first place?

Comment: A guess: You have allowed in the auto-blending dialog Photoshop to invent what it puts into the seam area and transparent areas. Making seamless compositions in Photoshop or in any photo editors became popular a long time before auto-blending was available. It took much longer time because it was our duty to make the color and light fit over the seam. Auto-blend was a delight. With it one can do the job fast if light condition nor surface texture differences don't make the case impossible. Your case very likely is difficult. Insert the images for us to see if you expect proper answers.

Comment: (continued) For non-auto-blend based methods make searches for "swap faces XXX" where XXX is something older than Photoshop CS3. Here's one example: https://easytweaks.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/how-to-replace-someones-face-using-adobe-photoshop/ As you can guess the difference must be a way smaller or at least consistent around the seam for reasonably easy job. The shown result isn't especially plausible due very different light conditions.

Comment: What you are doing is **not** what auto-blend was designed for. Auto-Blend is designed to take a collection of similar photographs and "blend" their edges. As in a series of images each as large as the camera can take.. then stitched together with auto-blend to create an image too large for any camera. Blending along seams. A face swap on a comic image is not suited for Auto-blend usage.

Comment: You can view the auto-blend help here: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/combine-images-auto-blend-layers.html and the little icon images when you choose the Auto-blend menu item *should* have alluded to is usage. Photoshop is not smart enough to know you are trying to create a "face swap" using an actual photograph and an illustration.